# C# Image Deskew

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, image-processing, image-manipulation

Has anyone seen any image deskew algorithms in c#? I have found:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/Deskew_an_Image.aspx

but unfortunately, it doesn't do very much for images without text.  I am specifically trying to auto deskew an image of a book with solid edges, but minimal text.

Has anyone seen anything that may be able to do this?

Comment: The algorithm there seems fine... just get a bunch of lines, find the line that satisfies `color at (x,y)` is `<book color>` and `color at (x,y+1)` is `<background color>`, and deskew based on that line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic algorithm is to use a Hough transform to find the lines and then try to make most of the lines horizontal.  Here's some basic code http://www.sydlogan.com/deskew.html

For your situation, you might want to target the transform at a piece of the image you know might have the best information.  For example if there's a page border -- I'd need to see an example to give better advice.

Disclaimer, I work at Atalasoft.

Our [DotImage](http://atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/) toolkit has it built in for .NET and is runtime royalty-free for desktop applications. Code would be:

```
 AtalaImage img = new AtalaImage("imagefile.tif");
 AutoDeskewCommand cmd = new AutoDeskewCommand();
 AtalaImage resultImage = cmd.Apply(img).Image;
 resultImage.Save("result.tif", new TiffEncoder(), null);
```

Or something similar for multipage or other types of images.

We show how to integrate it with our viewer control in this video (at 1:14)

http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/tutorials/capture/lesson4.aspx

The videos are part of a series of building a document scanning application:

http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/tutorials/capture/lesson1.aspx 
http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/tutorials/capture/lesson2.aspx 
http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/tutorials/capture/lesson3.aspx

Comment: If you post a sample image, I will run it through our code and let you know how it works.